# Automatic condition powershell creation thanks to the xml file value

Tags: xml, powershell

I currently have this powershell code that must be modified with each addition or deletion of "GUID App" that must be ignored and I am looking for a way to automate it by creating a powershell condition automatically create with the value contained in the xml file:

```
If (($data.guid -notlike "{4a5e080d-c6ba-4fb7-9562-f38168c86f14}") -and ($data.guid -notlike "{dc7f3eb0-ff06-4e9f-baa7-9b900070c928}") -and ($data.guid -notlike "{3394afd7-6e50-4bc3-b7db-e91116603bae}") -and ($data.guid -notlike "{69910266-a402-4cab-bc43-812f4f552e01}"))
    {
        # CODE POWERSHELL HERE
    }
else
    {
        # Nothing
    }
```

How to import this GUID between the "ignore_guid_app" tags of the xml file under the conditions of the following powershell code in order not to be required to modify the powershell code each time a GUID is added or deleted:

```
<informations>
  <deploymentshare>
    <path>\\192.168.XX.XX\DeploymentShare$</path>
    <name>MDT Deployment Share</name>
    <!-- username_deploy must be of the form IP_or_DNS\Username - Example : 10.0.1.2\Banbi or SrvMDT\Banbi -->
    <username_deploy>192.168.XX.XX\mdt</username_deploy>
    <!-- password_deploy must be empty at the start -->
    <password_deploy></password_deploy>
    <ignore_guid_app>{4a5e080d-c6ba-4fb7-9562-f38168c86f14};{dc7f3eb0-ff06-4e9f-baa7-9b900070c928};{3394afd7-6e50-4bc3-b7db-e91116603bae};{69910266-a402-4cab-bc43-812f4f552e01}</ignore_guid_app>
  </deploymentshare>
</informations>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the array of guids to ignore from the xml like this:

For demo I'm using a Here-String, but if this is from a file, change that to `[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path <thefile> -Raw`.

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<informations>
  <deploymentshare>
    <path>\\192.168.XX.XX\DeploymentShare$</path>
    <name>MDT Deployment Share</name>
    <!-- username_deploy must be of the form IP_or_DNS\Username - Example : 10.0.1.2\Banbi or SrvMDT\Banbi -->
    <username_deploy>192.168.XX.XX\mdt</username_deploy>
    <!-- password_deploy must be empty at the start -->
    <password_deploy></password_deploy>
    <ignore_guid_app>{4a5e080d-c6ba-4fb7-9562-f38168c86f14};{dc7f3eb0-ff06-4e9f-baa7-9b900070c928};{3394afd7-6e50-4bc3-b7db-e91116603bae};{69910266-a402-4cab-bc43-812f4f552e01}</ignore_guid_app>
  </deploymentshare>
</informations>
'@

$ignoreGuids = $xml.informations.deploymentshare.ignore_guid_app -split ';'
```

Then in your other code check using the `-notcontains` operator:

```
if ($ignoreGuids -notcontains $data.guid) {
    # CODE POWERSHELL HERE
}
else {
    # Nothing
}
```